# Integration by inverse trigonometric substitution

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to integrate by inverse trigonometric substitution, and I have an answer (though I'm pretty sure it is wrong), but it is not the answer that the solution provides. I need to check where I went wrong and what I should do differently.
This is the question:$$
\int\frac{1}{(a^2-x^2)^2}dx$$
And this is what I got:$$
\frac{1}{a^4}\frac{1}{2}(\sec\theta\tan\theta+\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|)+C=\frac{x}{2a^4(a^2-x^2)}+\frac{\ln|\frac{a+x}{2a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}|}{2a^3}+C$$
Whereas the solution should be:$$
\frac{x}{2a^2(a^2-x^2)}+\frac{1}{4a^3}\ln|\frac{x+a}{x-a}|+C$$
What I attempted was to do a by-parts once I got this: $$
\frac{1}{a^4}\int{\sec^3\theta d\theta} = \int\sec^2\theta\sec\theta d\theta
$$
Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: You need to edit a few things: (1) what was the inverse trig term you used for substitution? (2) Your last equation, has $\frac{1}{a^{4}}$ extra term on the left. (3) How did you get to that last line? It might be a good idea to show your solution since there might be something wrong there.

Comment: Yes, I used $a=\sin{x}$. Sorry about the last line, it should have a $\frac{1}{a^4}$ on the right-hand side as well. I did by parts for that to reach the line that I got in the second equation from the top. Integration by parts yielded: $\frac{1}{a^4}[\sec\theta\tan\theta-\int\sec\theta d\theta+ln|\sec\theta\tan\theta|]$. Then I got the second equation from the top. For the exponent, should it not be 3 because when I replace $dx$ I need to write $a\cos\theta d\theta$, so it cancels out 1 exponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitution $x=a\sin\theta$ to proceed as follows
\begin{align}
\int\frac1{(a^2-x^2)^2}dx 
=&\frac1{a^3} \int \sec^3\theta d\theta
= \frac1{2a^3} \int \frac{\sec\theta }{\tan\theta}d(\tan^2\theta)\\
=& \frac1{2a^3}\sec\theta\tan\theta + \frac1{2a^3} \int {\sec\theta }d\theta \\
 = &\frac1{2a^3}\sec\theta\tan\theta + \frac1{2a^3} \ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|\\
=  &\frac1{2a^3}\frac{\sin\theta }{\cos^2\theta}+ \frac1{2a^3} \ln|\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}|\\
 =&  \frac{x}{2a^2(a^2-x^2)}
+\frac{1}{2a^3}\ln|\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}|\\
 =&  \frac{x}{2a^2(a^2-x^2)}
+\frac{1}{4a^3}\ln|\frac{(a+x)^2}{a^2-x^2}|\\
=&  \frac{x}{2a^2(a^2-x^2)}
+\frac{1}{4a^3}\ln|\frac{x+a}{x-a}|
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, this is, for me, a lecture exercise for trigonometric substitutions so I must use $x=\sin\theta$.

Comment: @Memiya - no problem. please see the edit for the substitution approach

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I realised that my mistake was in replacing $\theta$ with $x$ at the end.